# SprinBoot micro service monitoring with Prometheus

Tags: spring-boot, monitoring, prometheus, dashboard

We are suggested to use the Prometheus tool to monitor the micro services developed using Spring Boot. i am not finding the examples on the similar scenarios, so can someone share the pointers on this

Comment: Did you go through spring metrics documentation? If not please check https://docs.spring.io/spring-metrics/docs/current/public/prometheus

Comment: @ChintanPandya the spring-metrics project is utterly outdated. It's the predecessor to the micrometer project. OP please have a look at the micrometer project and it's spring integration: https://micrometer.io/docs